# Jquery flip switch appending text

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

[image: This my problem]

[image: My desired output]

[Here is my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qp69Lmux/)

**Html**

```
<div 
     class="slider-toggle-container"
     style="float: left"
     data-initialvalue="0"
     data-height="32"
     data-width="82"
     data-ballwidth="32"
     data-tabindex="undefined"
     data-speed="550">

    <span id="myToggleLabel" class="slider-toggle-label-text">
        Like this toggle?
    </span>

    <label for="leftInput">YES</label>
    <input id="leftInput" type="radio" name="enabled" value="1">

    <label for="rightInput">NO</label>
    <input id="rightInput" type="radio" name="enabled" value="0">

</div>


        <div 
     class="slider-toggle-container"
     style="float: left"
     data-initialvalue="0"
     data-height="32"
     data-width="82"
     data-ballwidth="32"
     data-tabindex="undefined"
     data-speed="550">



    <label for="leftInput">YES</label>
    <input id="leftInput" type="radio" name="enabled" value="1">

    <label for="rightInput">NO</label>
    <input id="rightInput" type="radio" name="enabled" value="0">

</div>
```

My code here:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    jQuery('.slider-toggle-container').sliderToggle();

});
```

I'm getting the text is appending simultaneously in flip switch ? how can i fix this ?

Comment: Reduce your linked demo to the absolute *minimum* amount of code to demonstrate your problem, there looks to be far more jQuery, and HTML, and CSS, than necessary. Think "[MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/)."

Answer (score 3):

I think removing the Label Text .. solves the problem

```
    <label for="leftInput"></label>
    <input id="leftInput" type="radio" name="enabled" value="1">

    <label for="rightInput"></label>
    <input id="rightInput" type="radio" name="enabled" value="0">
```

Its because both the `class`,`ids` are similar

[**Try Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qp69Lmux/3/)

Comment: This does solve the issue, but it's **not** the right answer. The reason it works is because only one element with the same duplicated ID has text, so it's only gotten once. The solution is of cource to get rid of the duplicated ID's, not remove the text in some of the elements.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little hard to spot with the wall of code, but you're using **duplicate ID's for both sliders**, and that's the issue.

```
<div>
    <label for="leftInput">YES</label>
    <input id="leftInput" type="radio" name="enabled" value="1">

    <label for="rightInput">NO</label>
    <input id="rightInput" type="radio" name="enabled" value="0">
</div>
<div>
    <label for="leftInput">YES</label>
    <input id="leftInput" type="radio" name="enabled" value="1">

    <label for="rightInput">NO</label>
    <input id="rightInput" type="radio" name="enabled" value="0">
</div>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/qp69Lmux/4/)

When the labels and ID's match twice, it's not only invalid markup, but the plugin gets the text twice, which is why you see it two times in the sliders.